# How to Convert the below string into the array using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, string

How to convert the below string into array using php

String : `"[{\"site_id\":1,\"posts\":{\"0\":146,\"2\":104,\"3\":80},\"groups\":[{\"group_id\":1,\"site_id\":1,\"group_name\":\"Default List\",\"posts\":{\"0\":146,\"2\":104,\"3\":80}}]}]"`

php code: `json_decode(string, true)`;

I am using above code to convert the string into an array, **still no use**

can know to how to convert the string into the array

I want to get the posts id from the string.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please include the code you have attempted and the specific problem you ran into and need help with.

Comment: check the updated question

Comment: i have included the code i have tried to convert the string into the array

Comment: run the json through http://jsonlint.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your String is JSON -
so you could translate that JSON into the appropriate datatype in php simply by using the built int `json_decode` function

http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = "['a','b','c']";
var_dump(json_decode($json), true);
```

produces

```
array(3) {
[0] => 'a', 
[1] => 'b',
[2] => 'c'
```

}

Comment: what exactly doesn't function as you imagine? pls add the output of var_dump from your json_decode() :)

Comment: Thank you Chris for detailed explaination

Answer (score 1):

```
$jsonData = "[{\"site_id\":1,\"posts\":{\"0\":146,\"2\":104,\"3\":80},\"groups\":[{\"group_id\":1,\"site_id\":1,\"group_name\":\"Default List\",\"posts\":{\"0\":146,\"2\":104,\"3\":80}}]}]";    
$data = json_decode($jsonData);
```

Comment: i already tried the above method still no use can know another method